# как знать кто user у модели

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, создавал модель у которого есть user

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    zayavkadruzya = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
            related_name='addingfriend',
            blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

хочу отображать имя этого  user manytomanyitems

{{ user.userprofile.zayavkadruzya.user.get_full_name }}

но не работает

Answer (score 0):

Тогда надо, наверное, это сделать свойством объекта, а не класса.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        self.user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        self.zayavkadruzya = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
            related_name='addingfriend',
            blank=True,
            user=self)  # или user=self.user, какой там тип аргумента
```

(Если `models.OneToOneField` принимает аргумент `user`.)

Comment: не работает....

Comment: Скорее всего. Чтобы работало, надо все-таки подогнать под конкретную библиотеку, которой вы пользуетесь. Какие аргументы принимает ManyToManyField, как используется UserProfile, и т.п.